# Pyshark library memory issue

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pyshark

I Would like some help on managing memory consumption of pyshark library. Using it creates an effect of requiring more memory as you process more pcap files. I guess that something is no dereferenced and thus stays in memory forever.

For example if you run this script with any pcap file, you will see that the memory required keeps growing.

```
import pyshark

while(True):
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture("test.pcap")
    for p in cap:
        pass
    del cap
```

This is an issue for me with different versions of python and pyshark, so I suppose that I am missing something. Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: Why do you need `cap = pyshark.FileCapture("test.pcap")` inside while loop?

Comment: This is just  a test. In practice I am going to process multiple files one after another and it will practically create the same effect.

Comment: Are there any solution to this yet?